# Apache maximum request number 256?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a very good server running an Apache instance with mod_jk for proxying the request to an Application server.

I'm doing a load test and although I'm sending over 600 requests, the status worker keep showing this:

> 256 requests currently being processed, 0 idle workers

I'm using 'prefork MPM'

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
    ServerLimit          2048
    StartServers         5
    MinSpareServers      5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients           1000
    MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

Is there a compiled limit for Apache to handle just 256 request or what would I be missing?

Comment: Please add your complete MPM configuration (and which MPM you are actually using) to your question.

The directive StartThreads is only valid for the MPMs beos, mpm_netware, and perchild.

Answer (score 1):

Kamil, no it doesn't. MaxClients is fine being lower than ServerLimit. You can increase MaxClients up to ServerLimit and that adjustment can be done with a graceful restart. To increase ServerLimit, you have to do a full restart.

Answer (score 0):

compile with --mpm=worker

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [documentation for MaxClients](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients) you'll notice it mentions that you also need to set ServerLimit to be equal to the value of MaxClients. I think this is what you are missing.