# Apache MaxClients cannot override

Tags: apache-2.2

I cannot change MaxClients on my apacheserver, it just won't go over 256

```
256 requests currently being processed, 0 idle workers
```

MaxClients are set to 1024 in apache2.conf, i have no idea why it's not working.
I have read online that you have to stop and start the service instead of simply restarting, but that doesn't work.

Comment: similar to http://serverfault.com/questions/70956/apache-maximum-request-number-256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i found an answer. In the linked thread, someone mentioned that you have to define ServerLimit, to which someone responded it was not necessary, so i dismissed it at first. Turns out it works.

> If you read the documentation for MaxClients you'll notice it mentions that you also need to set ServerLimit to be equal to the value of MaxClients. I think this is what you are missing.